# Application.OnKey only for one spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use Application.OnKey to start a function when Enter is pressed, and it works just fine. But the problem is that if I have additional spreadsheets open it is applied to these as well. Where should I put the code so that it only works for the intended spreadsheet?

This is the code, which I have in "ThisWorkbook":

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnKey "~", "Set_Hyper"
    Application.OnKey "{ENTER}", "Set_Hyper"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Heres a way around it:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnKey "~", "Call_Hyper"
    Application.OnKey "{ENTER}", "Call_Hyper"
End Sub
```

In a module place this:

```
Sub Call_Hyper
If Activeworkbook.Name = "NAME OF YOUR WORKBOOK" Then
Call Set_Hyper
Else
Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

If the same shortcut is needed for another workbook the two will cause problems, so you can deactivate it when switching workbooks with the following too:

```
Private Sub Workbook_DeActivate()
    Application.OnKey "~"
    Application.OnKey "{ENTER}"
End Sub
```

You will need to change the first macro to a `Private Sub Workbook_Activate()` instead of `Private Sub Workbook_Open()` for the above to work though